# Is it possible to run 16GB DDR3 1.5V on a laptop with a Core i7 640M? (or any other CPU of that generation)

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu

First-generation laptop/mobile CPUs, such as the Core i7 620M or 640M, have a theoretical maximum of 8GB DDR3 according to official sites.

Has anyone successfully installed 16GB of DDR3 So-DIMM 1.5v on these older laptop chipsets/CPUs?

There are examples where going double from the recommended capacity is possible. On the desktop side of things, an i7 990X or a 970 for example, has a theoretical maximum of 24GB DDR3, but I have it paired with 48GB of ram for many years without any issues.

Thank you

Comment: Motherboard compatibility depends on the motherboard not the CPU.  However, the number of memory channels those processors supported would be determined by their Intel chipset.

Comment: So DDR3L or 1.5V? DDR3L is 1.35V, regular DDR is 1.5V.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry typo, ddr3 1.5V so-dimm, its for first-gen core I series.